# How to address a link inside jquery

Tags: jquery

Hy,

i tired a long time to get this done, but it seems to that my knowledge is too limited... damn!

I have this function now, where an image is loaded by default in the background and a accordion like menu, where one can click and than some divs fade in etc...

In the first part i set up the default image to load and define 2 links of the accordion:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $img = $('<img>', {
        src:    'images/home.jpg',
        load:   function() {
            $('#bg div table tr td').removeClass('loading').append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        css: {display:  'none'}    
        }).appendTo(document.body);

        $('a#the-story:not(.main-active)').live('click', function(){
            $img.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#bg div table tr td').addClass('loading');
                $img.attr('src', 'images/the-story.jpg');
            });
        });

        $('a#the-estate:not(.main-active)').live('click', function(){
            $img.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#bg div table tr td').addClass('loading');
                $img.attr('src', 'images/the-estate.jpg');
            });
        });

    });
```

Now i have my accordion:

```
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul.sub-1').hide();
    $('#menu ul.sub-2').hide();

    $('a:not(.main-active)').live('click', function(){

        var class = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#content ul').removeClass('active').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content ul.'+class).addClass('active').delay(300).fadeIn(1000);

        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if((checkElement.is('ul.sub-1')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            $('ul.sub-1:visible').slideUp('slow');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('main-active');
            $('a.main').removeClass('main-active');
            $('ul.sub-2:visible').slideUp('slow');
            $('ul.sub-2:visible').siblings().removeClass('sub-active');
            checkElement.slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('main-active');
            $('a#logo').removeClass('main-active');
            $('.newsletter').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if((checkElement.is('ul.sub-2')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            $('ul.sub-2:visible').slideUp('slow');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('sub-active');
            $('a.main').removeClass('sub-active');
            checkElement.slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('sub-active');
        }
        return false;
    }
);
}
```

That works fine for me. Now i want to add some function, where the jQuery.address can work, because i want an URL that than opens my accordion, but i couldn´t get it to work. I tried the examples but the accordion itself there didn´t work for me at all, because jQuery.accordion doesn´t support multilevels...

Any suggestion what i should do?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe i need a more simple question:

Would it be a way to check first the url, than say eg. if www.url.com/#sublink do this and that animation. Is that possiible?